# linking with cygwin1.dll

Tags: cygwin, dynamic-linking

I have a little application running on Linux and want to port it to Windows. I found that with Cygwin i will be able to do it simple by linking the application with the cygwin1.dll library which make available a lot of the POSIX and other standard functions. I read the FAQ and the User Guide on the site of Cygwin but didn't find or didn't understand how can I link my source with this library.
My application uses GTK+ and I successfully compiled and link it on Windows with MinGW but I have to disable some of the functionality .Now that I find Cygwin I would like to link with it to make available again this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you compile your source inside of Cygwin to produce the Windows binary. I'm pretty sure Cygwin will take care of linking to the proper dlls for you.

When you finally get the binary compiled, make sure that the cygwin1.dll is in the PATH specified by Windows.